# C++ std::regex validate integer incorrectly

Tags: c#, c++, regex

I have a simple regex express to validate user input is integer. In C# project, i see it validates correctly. Below is my code in C#:

```
string string_to_validate = Console.ReadLine();    
Regex int_regex = new Regex("[0-9]");
if (int_regex.IsMatch(string_to_validate))
    Console.WriteLine("Regex is match. Validation is success!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Regex is not match. Validation is fail!");
```

But in C++ i see it validates in correctly. It only validates correctly string with lengh is 1. Below is my code in C++:

```
std::string string_to_validate;
std::cin >> string_to_validate;
std::regex int_regex("[0-9]");
if (std::regex_match(string_to_validate,
                     int_regex))
  std::cout << "Regex is match. Validation is success!";
else
  std::cout << "Regex is not match. Validation is fail!";
```

Please help. It's C++ problem or my problem?

Comment: The two regular expressions you show are not the same.

Comment: The two regexes are different, what's the value of `string_to_validate`?

Comment: What you are trying to match?

Comment: `new Regex("[0-9]")` will find any ASCII digit anywhere in a string. `regex_match` with `"^[0-9]*$"` will only match a string find 0+ ASCII digits in it (an empty string, too).

Comment: Sorry about the two regexes are not same, i corrected it. **string_to_validate** is input from user.

Comment: Replace `std::regex_match` with `std::regex_search`

Comment: Replacing std::regex_match with std::regex_search make result is true whether string_to_validate contain numeric character. But i need the result is true if string_to_validate contain only numeric character.

Comment: Using a regular expression to check that a string consists entirely of digit characters is overkill; this can be done much more simply with a plain old loop and `std::isdigit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch(v=vs.110).aspx), the C# method `bool Regex.IsMatch(String)`

> Indicates whether the regular expression specified in the Regex
>   constructor finds a match in a specified input string.

So it will return `true` if there is at least one digit in the input string.

---

C++ [std::regex_match](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match)

> Determines if the regular expression matches the entire target
>   character sequence

So the whole input string must contains digits to pass the regex.

To validate string with integer of any length in C++ you have to use this regex:

```
 std::regex int_regex("[0-9]+"); // '+' - quantifier '1 or more' items from range [0-9]
```

or

```
 std::regex int_regex("\\d+");
```

Comment: std::regex_match return fail with input string "1", "11", "1111".

Comment: @PhungTienTrieu, it's strange. do your test strings have leading/tailing spaces?

Comment: It's ok now. But can you please expain why my original expression work in C# (System.Text.RegularExpression) but does not work in C++ (std::regex, std::regex_match)?

Comment: @PhungTienTrieu I edited the answer with details, why C# regex works, while C++ doesn't

Comment: very helpful. Thank you very much!